# select rows based on equal columns values

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

consider we have a table with this columns
Id
fk_newsId
fk_NewsGroupId
fk_NewsZoneId

I need to select all records with same fk_NewsGroup and fk_NewsZone
something like this

```
+----+-----------+--------------+-------------+
| Id | fk_NewsId | fk_NewsGroup | fk_NewsZone |
+----+-----------+--------------+-------------+
|  1 |        60 |            5 |           8 |
|  2 |        30 |            5 |           8 |
|  3 |        31 |            9 |          20 |
|  4 |         5 |            9 |          20 |
|  5 |        12 |            9 |          20 |
|  6 |      1000 |           20 |          11 |
|  7 |        21 |           20 |          11 |
|  8 |         6 |           20 |          11 |
+----+-----------+--------------+-------------+
```

how can do that?
I tride group by like this
but it dosnt give desired output

```
select fk_NewsId, fk_NewsGroup,fk_NewsZone  from tbl_test
group by fk_NewsGroup,fk_NewsZone,fk_NewsId
```

Comment: You mean order the records?

Comment: What have you tried?Could you show us your code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It seems you forgot to ask a question when posting your question.  What is it? What have you tried so far? Stack Overlow isn't a free coding website, it's a Q&A website for specific coding problems.

Comment: I tried group by, but it doesnt work

Comment: @juergen no not only order by, I need record with same fk_NewsGroup and fk_NewsZone without knowing what is actual value of fk_NewsGroup and fk_NewsZone

Comment: @lilifarabari I saw you edit your question and add some code. you can try my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `COUNT` with window function, to get the `count` by `fk_NewsGroup` and `fk_NewsZone` columns.

then get count greater than one.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT *,COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY fk_NewsGroup,fk_NewsZone ORDER BY fk_NewsZone) cnt
    FROM tbl_test
)t1
where t1.cnt > 1
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b6f5690bdaead08fc5ae2fee51885246)

Comment: @nealkernohan I write the wrong column in `ORDER BY`, thank for point out You can try it now.

Comment: who has given  -1 to this great anwer? It returns exactly what I needed

Comment: @lilifarabari it had an error was returning incorrect data, it has now been updated.   thanks d-shih for updating.

Answer (score 1):

Not absolutely clear as to what you mean, but something like so:

```
SELECT t.Id, t.fk_NewsId, t.fk_NewsGroup, t.fk_NewsZone FROM tbl_test t
INNER JOIN (
SELECT fk_NewsGroup,fk_NewsZone, COUNT(*) AS Counted FROM tbl_test
GROUP BY fk_NewsGroup,fk_NewsZone
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) g
ON t.fk_NewsGroup = g.fk_NewsGroup
AND t.fk_NewsZone = g.fk_NewsZone
```

[DBFiddle example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4ac04f24cf310dc14287eac338a4fe03)

Comment: this works with a little modification, I added order by fk_NewsZone and then it worked, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would use Group by and do it like:

```
select max(id) as Id, Max(fk_NewsId) as fk_NewsId, fk_NewsGroup,fk_NewsZone from #temp
group by fk_NewsGroup,fk_NewsZone
```